# Assigning Iterator to a non member struct in C++

Tags: c++, rocksdb

So I have this structure available and I have to make the output of the same format of the structure. However, whatever I have tried has not working and online search hasn't netted any results. I am getting error in the function that its->SeekToLast() can't be assigned

kvs.hh

```
`class KVS {
 public:
  struct Sentinel {};`
```

kvs.cc

```
auto KVS::end() const -> KVS::Sentinel {
  rocksdb::Iterator* its = db->NewIterator(rocksdb::ReadOptions());
  KVS::Sentinel sent;
  sent->its->SeekToLast();
  return sent;
}
```

```
In member function ‘cloudlab::KVS::Sentinel cloudlab::KVS::end() const’:
error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘cloudlab::KVS::Sentinel’ and ‘void’)
   72 |   sent = its->SeekToLast();
```

expecting to return the required value properly

Comment: The error message points to some code that you have not included in the question. At the very least the line it is complaining about does not exist in the code you posted

Answer (score 0):

Seek to last doesn't return anything.  You can't assign it to a variable.

You should seek to last and then return the iterator